# How to use np.where to display the index position + N where a condidtion is met

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops

I have a data frame where I am trying to create a new column when only a specific condition is met.

For example I have this line of code that I want to change to display a different output.

```
data['new_filtered'] = np.where(((data.movie == data.genre) & (data.length > movie_average)),1,0)
```

Instead of the return to be 1 and 0 for True and False, I want it to display `data.movie` but + 5 index positions.

For Example, if this condition is met at row 5 I want the return to be the movie at row 10.
I have done this in the past with just a for loop and appending that return value to a list and added that to the dataframe. I am just curious to see if this is possible with np.where().

Comment: please, send us some reproducible dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
mask = ((data.movie == data.genre) & (data.length > movie_average))
data['new_filtered'] = np.where(mask, data.movie.shift(-5), 0)
#                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I didn't know that you can create a mask. It makes it look much cleaner. I also didn't know about using a negative number in the shift but it makes sense!